# Moleculer sequlize get tables data by joins

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, moleculer

I am using moleculer micro services and postgres database with modules `moleculer-db-adapter-sequelize` and `Sequelize`. Every service have one table model. For e.g. `user.service.js` has user table model, `application.service.js` has application table model. I want to get data from both tables using join. I tried with join query but it returns

> Relation does not exist

How to make joins of two models in moleculer architecture?

Answer (score 1):

`moleculer-db` works as one-service-one-table concept. You should write your custom DB service to implement multiple models & joins.
In Moleculer level, the `populate` can be used to join data between services.

**Populate example:**

```
    settings: {
        fields: ["_id", "author", "article", "body", "createdAt", "updatedAt"],
        populates: {
            "author": {
                action: "users.get",
                params: {
                    fields: ["_id", "username", "bio", "image"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample code for populate between two services

Comment: I've added an example.